# Libreoffice calc, how to iterate over cells

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I like the program suite from LibreOffice.

I am trying to make a script/code/formula in LibreOffice calc that can count the number of words in the cells such as in the cell selection E5 to AT14

Something like this:
=LEN(E5:AT14)
=SUM(E5:AT14)

I don't know how to do it and I can not put them together, does anyone know how to do it? It may also be similar in excel if you know how to do it there.

Thanks !

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please leave a comment explaining how the question could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to count words in cells is to count the number of spaces and then add one, as explained by @Lyrl at https://superuser.com/questions/904590/libreoffice-how-to-count-words-and-characters-in-cells.

Answer (score 0):

This works, replace the cell names with the cells you want to affect, and it counts the letters.

=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(E5:AT14))

Thanks for also explaining how to count the words instead of letters.